# Does windows still use it's software based user keys when TPM-based EFS is enabled?

Tags: encryption, windows, tpm

I have an infineon TPM installed, with ownership taken, and EFS enabled with the TPM taking control of EFS for me.

I do know that regular EFS uses the windows user cryptography/login password to authenticate and decrypt.
I also do know that while using the TPM, it use's its own keys to encrypt and decrypt.

1. If I were to change the keys of my windows user, would that somehow
   invalidate the TPM using it's keys to conduct EFS?
2. Is there any connection between the two during the cryptography process?

In operation, the TPM is user aware, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have a problem with using a specific piece of software. Generally these questions are off-topic for this site, but you might find better luck at [superuser](//superuser.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//superuser.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I'm not having any issues, just curious into how it handles the keys.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Yeah, I agree with the OP, the core question is about _how it works_, not _how to use it_, so I think it's on topic here.